# NuGet package dependency source files are not embedded in project

Tags: nuget

We create and host NuGet packages in-house, with source code and deep dependency trees.  I'm having some issues getting dependencies to "behave".

For clarity, this is specifically installing packages via VS or Rider into a .Net Core / PackageReference project.  I don't expect it to be a VS/Rider/etc bug, so much as we're doing something slightly wrong.

**Scenario**:

- Create “Package A” using the PackageReference style compilation of
  “contentFiles/any/any”.

  - Create a sub-folder under “contentFiles/any/any” called “Source”.
  - Place source code files in the “Source” folder.
  - Have a dependency on “Package B”.
- Create “Package B”, again using the PackageReference style, with a “Source” subfolder.

  - Place source code files in its “Source” folder.
- Pack and publish both.

**Expectation**:

- Install “Package A” (using the built-in NuGet package manager UI).

  - Your project gains a “Source” folder.
  - A’s source files are referenced into the new “Source” folder and compile with the project.
  - “Package B” is also installed, since it’s a dependency.
  - B’s source files are also referenced into the “Source” folder and compile with the project.
- Package A is immediately consumable by the project because all of its code, and all of its dependency’s code, is present.

**Actual**:

- Install “Package A”.

  - Your project gains a “Source” folder.
  - A’s source files are referenced into the new “Source” folder and compile with the project.
  - “Package B” is also installed, since it’s a dependency.
  - B’s source files **are not referenced** into the “Source” folder.
  - **Package A code cannot be compiled because the source for B is not in the project.**
- Manually install “Package B”, same as you did for “A”.

  - B’s source files are referenced into the new “Source” folder in the project.
  - Now “Package A” can be compiled and consumed.

If sample nuspec files are needed, etc. please let me know.

Thanks

(This is a cross-post from https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8858.  No replies for a week)

Answer (score 0):

The post to NuGet's github (listed above) ended up with the solution.  When declaring the dependency in the nuspec, set the `include` to "Runtime,Compile,Native,ContentFiles,BuildTransitive" (or some combination thereof) and your dependency's files will correctly embed.  I'm still working through the differences between the options, but there you have it.